# MPI and hierarchical collectives - missing 'hierarch' coll module from OpenMPI 2.x?

Tags: mpi

I'm working on an application that is critically dependent on the performance of MPI_Alltoall calls with very small messages (less than 4KB) flying among a large number of processes (currently about 200, while the target is in the thousands and more).

I was under the impression, and reading [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2642769.2642770) seems to corroborate that impression, that it would be sensible to exploit the hierarchy of a modern PC cluster (as the one I have at my disposal) by segregating processes belonging to a single cluster node within separate communicators (OpenMPI even has a function, from the MPI 3 standard, that does just that) and then, instead of an MPI_Alltoall over MPI_COMM_WORLD, using a sequence MPI_Gather - MPI_Alltoall - MPI_Scatter whereas Gather and Scatter are restricted within those communicators while the Alltoall is over another communicator including one and one only 'gatherer' process per node, in this way exploiting the supposedly faster transfers in internal memory for the Gather and Scatter while hopefully increasing the efficiency of the Alltoall among nodes by having fewer, larger messages passing through the network interfaces (ConnectX InfiniBand NICs by Mellanox, in my case).

I'm trying to verify the assertions of the paper, and if someone is interested I can share my findings, but what I wanted to know is this: perusing the 1.10.x OpenMPI sources, I clearly see a 'hierarch' component among the 'coll' modules, which is also mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/README) that makes it seem like such a hierarchical implementation had been pulled in already.

Nevertheless, I was never able to make it work and it seems that it vanished altogether from the 2.x branch (there is none in the 'ompi_info' output).

Is there anyone that succeeded in using it? Can you tell about any improvements, if any, compared to a regular MPI_Alltoall?

Comment: `coll/hierarch` has been removed from Open MPI from v2. in order to use it with 1.10, you can `mpirun --mca coll_hierarch_priority 100 ...`

Comment: i'll have references to `coll/hierarch` removed from recent `README`

Comment: OK, I was misled by what was probably a mention in the README of a module which is no longer supported; anyway, when I say I was unable to make it work is because I already tried to follow the directions in the README regarding `mpirun --mca coll_hierarch_priority 100` and 'hierarch' doesn't trigger (as can be seen by increasing the verbosity of the 'coll' component with `-mca coll_base_verbose 10000` and finding a number of `coll:base:comm_select: component not available: hierarch` messages in the output without any further reasons as to why) or simply segfaults.

Comment: the `coll/hierarch` module silently disqualifies itself if you are running less than 3 MPI tasks, or if there is only one level in the hierarchy (that typically occurs when you run on one node). i also noted `coll/hierarch` works fine with `btl/openib` (and one shared memory btl), but not if i use `btl/tcp` and the shared memory btl (!)

Comment: That much I thought, since the run does not crash if the processes are all on the same node, but even with just 4 processes on two nodes I see many `coll:base:comm_select: component not available: hierarch` in the verbose output of the `coll` module (which makes me think the module disqualifies itself already) while it just crashes with 6 processes on 2 nodes.

Comment: can you post a simple test case that crashes ? what kind of interconnect do you have ?

Comment: One test that crashes is simply the `osu_alltoall` in the [OSU Micro-Benchmarks](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks) suite when invoked like this:
`mpirun -mca coll_hierarch_priority 100 -mca pml ob1 -mca coll_base_verbose 10000 --display-map -n 6 -host q000,q000,q000,q001,q001,q001 bash -c 'ulimit -s 10240; ./osu_alltoall -m 512:512 -x 1000 -i 100 -f'`.
Our cluster has an ordinary GbE interconnect plus an InfiniBand one provided by ConnectX NICs and a Mellanox InfiniBand switch.